# localStorage is not working fine for me. Why does this happen?

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know what's the problem of the codes shown below.
Please somebody tell me what should I do to get a result.

**HTML:**

```
Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name"></input>
            <button id="send" type="submit" onclick="qwe()">SEND</button>
    <div id="test">START</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function qwe() {
  var user=localStorage.getItem('user');
  if (user != "") {
    document.getElementById('name').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('send').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "Welcome back " + user;
  } else {
     if (user != "" && user != null) {
       let xdf = document.getElementById("name").value;
      localStorage.setItem('user', xdf);
     }
  }
}
```

**The result is:** *(Successfully hides input element)*

```
Name:
Welcome back null
```

Comment: You're only checking if the user is an empty string, not if it's `null` or `undefined`. You likely want to change your condition to `if (user) { //do stuff }`

Comment: Your first condition is `if (user != "")`, then in the `else` of this condition you have yet an inner condition `if (user != "" && `. Read this out loud, or even replace this condition with something more idiomatic: "if condition A do somethign, else if condition A and condition B do an other thing." So you see how you can never reach the other thing? If condition A is reached, the `else` will not be. And for the condition inside that `else` to be reached, condition A needs to be reached... catch 22, you never write anything to the storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need

```js
function qwe() {
  var user=localStorage.getItem('user');
  if (user) {
    document.getElementById('name').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('send').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "Welcome back " + user;
  } else {
    let xdf = document.getElementById("name").value;
    if (xdf) {
      localStorage.setItem('user', xdf);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Or just `if (user)`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your user is not being stored in your localStorage.

html

```html
<input type="text" id="name" name="name"></input>
<button id="send" type="submit" onclick="qwe()">SEND</button>
<div id="test">START</div>
```

js

```js
const userName = document.querySelector('input');
const test = document.getElementById('test');

const updateValue = () => {
  localStorage.setItem('user', userName.value)
}

const qwe = () => {
  var user=localStorage.getItem('user');
  if (!user) {
    document.getElementById('name').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('send').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "Welcome back " + user;
  } else {
      userName.addEventListener('change', updateValue);
    }
  }
}
```

I haven't been able to test run the code, but feel free to let me know it it's not working

Comment: I tried this code an I ran into an error saying only available on ES6. Looks like your syntax usage is outdated man. But thanks for helping.